# What is the best OS to run an Ethereum node on?

Tags: nodes

It was recommended that running your own node is beneficial for learning as well as for the network and community.

Is there any reason to use one OS over another for running an Ethereum node?

I might dive into mining for research and study purposes but I don't plan on using it to mine Eth or anything of the sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're building a new machine just to run Ethereum, something no-frills, such as a "server" distribution of Linux, is a good idea, since the OS adds little overhead (I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 for mine).

If it's a machine you already own, and already use for other things (which should be fine, as long as it's reasonably powerful), just use the OS that's already installed - Geth and Parity support a wide range of architectures, so you probably don't need to change OS.

Comment: Are you saying a server distribution of linux or a server with a linux distro running on it. Thanks @James_

Comment: I'm saying a server distribution of Linux. The difference between a low-end server and a workstation is mostly what you use it for. A workstation you no longer have a use for is a viable server. For an Ethereum node, the most important thing you need is an SSD.

Comment: Which Ethereum node software are you running?  I ask because I setup an Eth node using `go ethereum` in a docker container, but it keeps crashing.

Comment: I personally prefer Parity, but I wouldn't expect Geth to behave that differently. The usual thing that causes crashes, in both cases, is not enough RAM. If you're using Docker for Windows, be aware that Docker may not be getting access to your whole system's RAM.